# Podspec fails validation with valid Swift 3 syntax

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcodebuild, swift3, podspec

I'm working on one of my projects (https://github.com/mamaral/Neon) that I've made available via CocoaPods, but since I've migrated to Swift 3.0 I've been unable to release this update as my podspec fails validation.

The first example of one of the errors I'm seeing (I'm hoping the fix for one will be the fix for all) is this:

> warning: extraneous '_' in parameter: 'align' has no keyword argument name

This is in reference to the following function declaration:

```
public func align(_ align: Align, relativeTo sibling: Frameable, padding: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, offset: CGFloat = 0) {}
```

My project compiles/runs fine, without warnings/errors, although it may be relevant that the `xcodebuild` command also fails as well, so I'm not sure what the issue is here. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try `_:` or removing `_` altogether and see what happens...

Comment: I am having the same issue but xcodebuild passes. Seems xcodebuild is expecting Swift 2.3 syntax. Have you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue as well. I had a pod in valid Swift 3 syntax but Cocoapods was using the Swift2.3 compiler.

It seems Cocoapods now supports a [`.swift-version`](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/5841) file to specify the version of Swift to be used (it uses Swift 2.3 as default).

Comment: Awesome I'll check this out ASAP.

Comment: What if I'm writing the project in Objective-C, how do I avoid this error?